# Prove that for all $n > 2$, we have $F_j < F_n $ for every $j$ in $\{1, \dotsc ,n-1\}$ (Fibonacci Sequence)

Tags: proof-writing, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to show the following, where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers.

> Prove that for all natural numbers $n > 2$, we have $F_j < F_n $ for every $j$ in $\{1, \dotsc ,n-1\}$.

I am not sure how to interpret this question. Is it asking to prove for $F_1 < F_3$ all the way to $F_{n-1}$ to $F_{n+1}$? Or is it asking to prove for any $F_j$ there is an $F_n$ that is larger?

In the earlier part of the question, we had to prove that $F_n > 0$ for all natural numbers $n$. So would we just use that statement to say that $F_n$ is always a sum of two consecutive positive numbers hence $F_n$ is always larger than the previous term $F_{n-1}$ for all natural $n$?

Comment: Is  $F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$  with  $F_1=F_2=1$?

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to prove that for example $F_{j}\leqslant F_{50}$ for all $j\in\{1,2,...,49\}$ and that $F_{j}\leqslant F_{51}$ for all $j\in\{1,2,...,50\}$ and so on. The effect would be that this would prove that if $j\leqslant n$ then $F_j \leqslant F_n$ assuming the restriction on n holds. From what I can tell youd either need to vary the type of induction or youd have to prove that $F_n \leqslant F_{n+1}$ if $n\geqslant 1$. Hope this helps.

Edit: I think the varied induction is probably better. The variation is like this  $P(m)\land(\forall n>m)[\land_{m\leqslant x\leqslant n-1} P(x)\implies P(n)]\implies \forall n P(n)$. So in practice this would look something like this:

Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n n=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$. The base case can be $n=1$ $\sum_{k=1}^1=1=\frac{1}{2}*2=\frac{1}{2}*1*(1+1)$. Then we'd assume that it holds for $n=1, n=2, n=3$, and on and on till $n=k-1$, and then prove that holds for $n=k$. This would imply it holds for n=k.

Edit 2: Nvm seems like you had gotten a result I didnt and was assuming you hadn't proved it(the $F_n >0$ result) which makes things much easier.

Comment: Could I just show that Fn > Fn-1? I would do this by using the proof I did in the earlier part whereby I showed that Fn>0 for all natural n. And since Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2, could I use the fact that Fn is a sum of two of the two previous positive numbers (Fn-1 and Fn-2) to show that Fn-1>Fn-2>...>F1?

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt see the part about the $F_n>0$ proof. If you did that then yes it would most definately work. That simplifies things a lot. May I ask how you did it?

Comment: i used strong induction. So the base case is F3 = 2 >0 then i assume for F3,F4,...Fk >0 for some k>2. Then for n = k+1, Fk+1 = Fk + Fk-1, then using the induction hypothesis Fk+1 is a sum of two positive numbers so Fk+1>0